# Главная страница joomla 2,5 в виде блога

Tags: joomla

У меня появилась проблема с отображением элементов на главной странице в виде блога.

Цифрой 1 обозначена проблема, т.е. не могу убрать этот серый фон и сделать его прозрачным. Не могу найти, где это менять. Сайт стоит на шаблоне designwerks. Цифрой 2 обозначено то, что у модуля фон я могу сделать прозрачным. Что делать? Куда смотреть? Где копать? Спасибо за помощь.)

[image]

Comment: http://i3.imageban.ru/out/2012/05/31/f21477ca59b66301e21151870c4e6100.jpg ссылка на скриншот

Comment: так вот в этом и проблема, не могу понять в каком файле копать

мой ответ с другого форума

да, спасибо, только что заметил, у параграфов был задан бэкграунд-колор #fcfcf7 ) если прямо указать в каждом новом параграфе что бг не должно быть, все становится таким каким я хочу видеть.
Ссылку на страницу дать не могу, так как все пока на денвере  Не могли бы подсказать как глобально изменить этот самый бэкграунд-колор для параграфов?

Answer (score 1):

ну модуль отвечает за баннер - это понятно и правельно что он может сделатся прозрачным. А за фон текста на шаблоне отвечает файлик ---.сss там и копать.